# FQL friends_request empty result

Tags: php, facebook-fql

Currently I'm querying the FQL `friends_request` table but it's returning the empty result...
I have the `read_request` permission

here is my code:

```
try {
      $fql = 'SELECT uid_from, time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()';
      $ret_obj = array(
                       'method' => 'fql.query',
                       'query' => $fql );
                       $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($ret_obj);  

foreach($fqlResult as $result)
{
  print_r($result);

}
```

Comment: make sure you have the `read_requests` extended permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the same query using the Graph API (working for me):

```
try {
// ...
    $fql = urlencode('SELECT uid_from, time, message FROM friend_request WHERE uid_to = me()');
    $fqlResult = $facebook->api("/fql?q=$fql");
    if(!empty($fqlResult['data'])) {
        foreach($fqlResult['data'] as $result) {
            print_r($result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get data too (as I have a current friend request pending on my account).